# Add '1' to all cells in a range

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I'm trying to add a unit of `1` to many cells in a range.  Below is where I'm at and I keep getting a type mismatch error:

```
Dim r As Range, cell As Range

Set r = Range("D2:E1000")

For Each cell In r
    If cell.Value > 0 Then
        cell.Value = cell.Value + 1
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Do you want to append a "1" to what's currently in the cell? Or replace the contents of the cell with a "1"?  (I'm assuming the former based on your code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
Sub marine()
    Dim r As Range, cell As Range

    Set r = Range("D2:E1000")

    For Each cell In r
        If IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then
            If cell.Value > 0 Then
                cell.Value = cell.Value + 1
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "Cell " & cell.Address(0, 0) & " does not have a number"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: The field is actually a time in the form of "h:mm AM/PM".  I am trying to add one day.  I can do it with a single cell, but not all cells in a range.

Comment: @user2887400: if you have a time in those slots, what are you trying to do with the time?  I think adding 1 to a time would result in the same time.  Is there a date also in the field that you are trying to increment?

Comment: If a cell contains date/time, then adding one to that cell will increment the date by 1 day.

Comment: @Gary's Student: You are right.  It did increase by one day which is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another way

```
Sub Sandwich()

    Dim rTemp As Range
    Dim rTarget As Range
    Dim sNumFmt As String

    'Define the ranges
    Set rTemp = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Set rTarget = Sheet2.Range("D2:E1000")

    'store a temporary value and the current number format
    rTemp.Value = 1
    sNumFmt = rTarget.Cells(1).NumberFormat

    'copy and paste special-add
    rTemp.Copy
    rTarget.PasteSpecial , xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd

    'get rid of the temp and reapply the format
    rTemp.ClearContents
    rTarget.NumberFormat = sNumFmt

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Stopping at `OK, I'm trying to add a unit of "1" to many cells in a range.` the easiest way is often without VBA or code. Just insert `1` somewhere on the spreadsheet, copy that cell, select the range of interest and Paste Special with Operation Add. The `1` can then be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim r As Range, cell As Range

Set r = Range("D2:E1000")

For Each cell In r
    If cell > 0 Then
        cell.Value = cell.Value + 1
    End If
Next
```

Is Working for me , perhaps you want IF cell = 0 ???
Waiting for your comments to see if i anwsered your question.